# Select cells containing specific texts in specified row and shift cells down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select the cells that contain strings "NNN", "MG","FS","N","IG" etc. in Row 7 and Shift those cells down.

I got an error, also I didn't get the idea how to use multiple criteria ("NNN","MG","FS") for selection.

[image: Screenhot of Excel File]

```vb
Sub select_text_and_shiftdown()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("Input")
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("7:7"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "NNN") > 0 Then
            r.Application.Selection.inset shift = xlDown  
       End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Instr(1,v,”NNN”). And selection.insert will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. May try

```
Sub select_text_and_shiftdown()
Dim r As Range, v As Variant
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim Chk As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Chk = Array("NNN", "MG", "FS", "N", "IG")
Set w1 = Sheets("Input")
w1.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(Range("7:7"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
        For i = LBound(Chk) To UBound(Chk)
            If InStr(v, Chk(i)) > 0 Then
            'r.Application.Selection.inset shift = xlDown
            r.Insert xlShiftDown
            Exit For
            End If
        Next i
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked !, Thank You so much, that's what exactly I am looking for. SO & you guys are amazing. :)